# Mobx components re-rendering of components after state changes

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm introducing Mobx in my React application. The application was not using any framework(Flux Redux, etc).

On each component i first inject the state using the `inject` decorator of the `mobx-react` package:

```
const React = require('react');
import {observer, inject} from 'mobx-react';

@inject('myState') @observer
class MyComponent extends React.Component{...}
```

On updates i change directly the state on the onChange method of the component, the state contains an array of objects(`blocks`) and each block has some specific properties:

```
onChange = (event) => {
    this.props.myState['blocks'][this.props.index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  }
```

I then render the component using the value fetched from the state.

```
render = () => {
    const value = this.props.myState['blocks'][this.props.index]['myInput'];

    console.log('re rendering...');

    return (
        <div>
            <textarea value={value}
                      onChange={this.onChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But actually it seems like the render function is not triggered after the `onChange` has been executed and the state `myState` changed.

Any suggestions about how come the re render is not triggered even if the component is a state subscriber?

Comment: Have you tried without a property initialized arrow function as your render method? I.e. `render() { ... }`, not `render = () => { ... }`?

Comment: @Tholle why should that matter? it's just syntactic sugar, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm just grasping at straws here. I can't see something wrong with your code. Have you tried removing the blank line after `@inject('myState') @observer`? Also, `event` is not defined in the render method, so `[event.target.name]` might not work as expected.

Comment: @Tholle you're right on both indeed. But still the component does not re render.

Comment: Have you tried just hard coding the value in `onChange`? `this.props.myState['blocks'][this.props.index]['myInput'] = event.target.value;`.

Comment: I think the issue is related to the structure of the state. `this.props.myState['blocks']` is an array and changing one property of one item does not change the array value. I'm currently investigating on that.

Comment: Probably `this.props.myState['blocks'][this.props.index]` does not have a member named `event.target.name` before. It that case, You are adding a non-observable member to `this.props.myState['blocks'][this.props.index]`. It is better to use `Map` in these cases.

Comment: Note that observable arrays only support numbered keys, otherwise use observable objects, or, if the keys are dynamic, observable maps

Comment: @alisabzevari the property is initialized, than that's not the case. Anyway i tried with map and still it doesn't re render.

Comment: @mweststrate I'm using an observable state with a nested array of objects. Might it be the case that mobx does not re render on the changes on nested properties?

Comment: Can we see MyState class?